# pandas.DataFrame.agg does not work with np.std?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am trying to use the **pandas.DataFrame.agg** function on the **first column** of a dataframe with the **agg** function is **numpy.std**.
I dont know why it works with **numpy.mean** but not **numpy.std**?
Can someone tell me in what circumstance that happens.
This is very strange @@
The following describes what I am facing.

My source is like this:

```
print(type(dataframe))
print(dataframe.head(5))
first_col = dataframe.columns.values[0]
agg_df = dataframe.agg({first_col: [np.mean]})
print(agg_df)
```

then it shows the result like this

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
        ax
0   -98.06
1   -97.81
2   -96.00
3   -93.44
4   -92.94

            ax
mean   -98.06
```

now I change the function **from np.mean into np.std** (**without** changing anything else)

```
print(type(dataframe))
print(dataframe.head(5))
first_col = dataframe.columns.values[0]
agg_df = dataframe.agg({first_col: [np.std]})
print(agg_df)
```

it shows the errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\predictions\predictor.py", line 112, in pre_aggregated_unseen_data
    agg_df = dataframe.agg({axis: [np.std]})
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7578, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7609, in _aggregate
    return aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py", line 582, in aggregate
    return agg_dict_like(obj, arg, _axis), True
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py", line 768, in agg_dict_like
    results = {key: obj._gotitem(key, ndim=1).agg(how) for key, how in arg.items()}
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py", line 768, in <dictcomp>
    results = {key: obj._gotitem(key, ndim=1).agg(how) for key, how in arg.items()}
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3974, in aggregate
    result, how = aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py", line 586, in aggregate
    return agg_list_like(obj, arg, _axis=_axis), None
File "C:\prediction_framework_django\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py", line 672, in agg_list_like
    raise ValueError("no results")
ValueError: no results
```

So the error is
**in agg_list_like raise ValueError("no results") ValueError: no results**

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the pandas builtin:

```py
# Note the use of string to denote the function here
df.agg({first_col: ['mean', 'std']})

# You can also simply use the following
df[first_col].mean()
df[first_col].std()
```

[EDIT]: The error that you are getting is probably resulting from mixed types. You can check that all dtypes are float by looking at `df.dtypes`. If you have one that is `object`, then convert the problematic ones (probably empty strings) into whatever you need and `np.std` and pandas' builtin `std` should work

Comment: Thanks, I have a dataframe with the columns like  ['ax', 'ay', 'az', 'gx', 'gy', 'gz'] 
Each of different column I want to agg with some functions, that should represent by a dict type like this
{'ax': ['mean', 'std'], 'ay': ['max', 'mean', 'std', 'median']}
that means with each of column I want to apply different functions set. 
I implemented as my strategy like this
features_dict = {'ax': ['mean', 'std'], 'ay': ['max', 'mean', 'std', 'median']}
for key in features_dict:
   df_temp = df.agg({key: features_dict[key]})
The thing is it worked with all other functions but not the std @@

Comment: please surround your pieces of code with `

Comment: Thank you, I will check it  for a try but I believe that might not come from the data itself as it worked with other function like median, mean.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice helped me to solve the problem!